Which is the best results for Plasmid dna extraction on gel electrophoresis?

I did plasmid dna extraction and uploaded on the gel.
Well 1: marker
Well 2: nicked,circular,and supercoiled bands
Well 3: linear,circular,and supercoiled bands
Well 4: circular and supercoiled bands.
Which one is the best result?

What do you mean by "Best"?

Best extraction

You still have not explained what you mean by “best”. Do you mean “highest yield”, “most un-nicked” or what? Do you know what the different bands represent? If, as I suspect, you do not then you need to find out for yourself. You could even search this site to find a photo I included in an answer to a previous question. But we expect posters to provide context to their questions, and evidence of their own attempts to find an answer.

My professor asked me this one, and I’m not sure what do we mean by the best here. I’ll check and edit then the question. Thank you

This is very obviously homework. Please see the [help] for the homework policy.
